# on finite division subring of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Is there any example of a ring which is not a division ring but any of its  subring is a division ring?

According to me if $R$ is a ring and $S$ is a division subring then $1\in S$ and hence $R=S$. Is it true?

Comment: How did u conclude $R=S$?

Comment: Perhaps you meant "...any of its *proper* subrings" . Besides, from $\;1\in S\;$  you can't in general deduce $\;S=R\;$ . This is true if $\;S\;$ is an *ideal*, but not in general if it is merely a subring.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example is the product ring $\mathbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2$ (the Klein four group). Every proper nonzero subring is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2$, which is a division ring.